# How to find path to filtervalue

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

Can you help me how to find a path to desired `filtervalue`, such as value `Search in active documents`?

As you can see in the picture, the class `filtervalue` is there multiple times.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll consider XPath. It seems you'd need to use `text()` as well:

`//span[@class="filtervalue" and contains(text(), "Search")]`

You don't need to use `contains()`, you can use just `text()=`, but it seems to me that the text value might change, so `contains()` might apply even after the change.